# why hoisted variable in js is showing not defined

Tags: javascript

While reading the documentation for js i found the variable used and not declared in a js function will be hoisted and become a global scope

```js
console.log(x);

function trial() {
  x = 5;
  console.log(x);
}
trial();
```

the first line gives me an error "VM48:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
at :1:13"
but when I declare var x on top

```js
var x;
console.log(x);

function trial() {
  x = 5;
  console.log(x);
}
trial();
```

Now the first console print undefined when undeclared variable is hoisted than why the x is not passed to global scope and gives me undefined in first case ?

Comment: It's not the `x=5` that causes any hoisting but the `var x` declaration. There is no `var` in your first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The variable used and not declared in a JS function will be hoisted
> and become a global scope."

That's not completely true. I don't know what's the source of the documentation you're reading, but or it's inaccurate or you've misinterpreted it.

If you assign a value to a variable that hasn't been declared, **it will not be hoisted**. It's just going to be a global variable. Hence, in your example, you're only going to print "5" instead of getting an exception if you run the `trial()` function **before** running `console.log(x)` outside that function.

```js
trial();
console.log(x);

function trial() {
  x = 5;
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Since, `x` here is a global variable, but NOT hoisted, is it still a part of the Global Execution Context ? Or hoisted/NOT hoisted has nothing to do with a variable being a part of GEC ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example doesn't hoist anything - hoisting only occurs when using `var`, and in your first example it was the first line of the function regardless.  Hoisting would be something like this (where `var x` is "hoisted" to the top - but *not* the initialization of `5`, but `y` is not hoisted at all):

```js
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
function trial(){
    console.log(x);
}
trial();
var x = 5;
y = 5
```

Or, to be even more clear:

```js
var x = 5;
console.log(x); // 5;
(() => {
    // hoisted: var x;
    console.log(x); // undefined;
    var x = 6;
    console.log(x); // 6
})();
```

Comment: But doesnt it says that a variable which is not declared but used became a global variable , so it must be hoisted on top @dave

Comment: Why "must" it be hoisted?  It obviously isn't, your own code demonstrates that.  And there are multiple examples showing that is not the case here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: So how does a var become global when not declared and used @dave

Comment: oki look you guys let's stop with this misunderstood of how js really works.

Comment: @abhishekvashistha It doesn't become a `var`, it becomes an implicit property of the global object (nearly equivalent to a global variable) when doing an *assignment to an undeclared variable*. In any case, this is a legacy behaviour and is forbidden in strict mode, it will just throw an exception. Simply always declare your variables and don't bother about [implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).